# Solving 2D Heat Equation with Input using central finite difference method

Tags: pde

So I have implemented central finite difference method for solving the 2D heat equation. When I leave all initial and boundary conditions as 0s, but apply an input uniform across the entire space or grid, I am only noticing temperature response at the boundary. I am not sure exactly what is causing this.

The code is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YCh_DDrw0uZPLvrWKU2hcw6lSe7cQiRS

But for a quick example of what this looks like:

[image]

Would really appreciate any help with looking at the code to see what's causing this. Is there any chance that my algorithm is unstable and I need to increase the discretization points or something?

Comment: I expect nobody is going to help, because your code requires asking for access.

Comment: @JoschaFregin I just edited the access permission to anyone with the link

Comment: In your code's `odefunc` function, you take `T` as an argument and then promptly set it ot the zero matrix. That's likely not what you intended.

Comment: Okay, I corrected this, I also set the initial dTdt to be empty instead of zeros as well. This should be fine, correct? I am still seeing a weird plot now however if you look back at the code. It looks like maybe some of the ODE solutions for some of the points are diverging?